# Is there C++ API for Delaunay triangulation in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, triangulation, delaunay

I'm trying to implement one of active appearance models (AMM) and on one of the steps I need to get **triangulated mesh of a face**, e.g.:

[image]

**Delaunay triangulation** seems to be a good fit for this task (correct me if there are better options), and OpenCV has [C API for it](http://books.google.by/books?id=seAgiOfu2EIC&pg=PA302&lpg=PA302&dq=opencv+delaunay+triangulation+example&source=bl&ots=hSH09ldJT9&sig=fwMYUitawVOExjK3qoSbv3DQO6c&hl=be&sa=X&ei=jtflT46xJ4_c4QTL6vijAQ&ved=0CGMQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q&f=false). But is there **C++ API** for Delaunay triangulation? Of course if is not a big deal to write a wrapper for C version if there's really no C++ API, but it's possible that's just lack of my knowledge of API, and not the API itself. In this case I will definitely prefer native OpenCV implementation.

Comment: Original image and corresponding article are [here](http://codecapsule.com/2010/08/12/active-appearance-models-in-c-plus-plus/).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

OpenCV has C++ API for delaunay triangulation, but unfortunately it is not documented.

Here are the class [Subdiv2D](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/subdivision2d.cpp) implementing delaunay algorithm and usage [example](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/delaunay2.cpp).

Comment: Broken links are now fixed.

Comment: They are broken again.